# Cannot connect with mongo db (cf ssh) - MongoNetworkError

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I want to connect my local NodeJS app with the Swisscom Cloud Foundry MongoDB service instance. 
As I see in the service key, there are three ports for mongo db.
So, I bind the ports with the cf ssh ports.

```
cf ssh -L 63307:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:37268 {my binded app}
cf ssh -L 63308:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:39279 {my binded app}
cf ssh -L 63309:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:45817 {my binded app}
```

After successfully run `cf ssh`, I'm not able to connect to my MongoDB and get a network error `(MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:63308])` in NodeJS (`mongoose connect with the dtabase_uri`). Same behavior with MongoDB Compass client.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you edit your question with the command `mongo -vvv` you use to connect and the exact command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a hosts entry on your system to resolve `kubernetes-service-node.service.consul` to `127.0.0.1`?

Also, I think you don't need to open three SSH connections, i.e. I think you can specify several port forwardings in a single connection like this: `cf ssh -L ... -L ... -L ... <app>`

Comment: Do I have to add the host entry on the hosts file (on my mac) or isn't it just possible to change the connection string to localhost like this:

`"mongodb://xyz@127.0.0.1:63310,127.0.0.1:63311,127.0.0.1:63312/abc?replicaSet=efg"` 

after binding with 

`cf ssh -L 63310:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:37268 -L 63311:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:39279 -L 63312:kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:45817 {appname} `
?

Comment: You have to add it, as the mongod servers you're connecting to will tell your client/driver the "correct" addresses and then it will try to connect to those instead of the ones you specified.

Comment: After adding the host to the hosts file and remove the replicationSet Parameter from the connection string, the connection works fine! Thanks.